# ICMP flood with ping working only one time

Tags: networking, bash, ping, tcpdump, icmp

my problem is simple:

The first time I made a flooding ping to a fake ip on my network (for testing if someone is on promisc mode), it works perfectly:

```
$ping -f 192.168.1.10
```

After perfoming this, my machine 192.168.1.4 on promisc mode running tcpdump was flooded as hell and I can test it with a normal ping from another host.

But after that test, the second time I ran this command, only a few messages from tcpdump was displayed and my flooder host was printing on shel just dots, a large amount of dots.

Why since the second time I ran this flooding commmand stop working?

thanks for all and sorry for my bad english

Comment: What else is on your network? What software is on the machines, that could be the cause?

Comment: The network is a subnet on my pc builded with VirtualBox, all the hosts on the network are Debian machines. One of them in promisc mode.

Comment: Dots represent ICMP packets which didn't get a response. Looks like you ping-flooded `192.168.1.10` to death.